# database transaction protection for web application - recommended or performance drain?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, web

Is there a recommendation about building in database transaction protection on a web platform? A number of our screens insert/update into multiple tables and for me, wrapping these multiple inserts in a transaction is the obvious solution, i.e. where we commit if all inserts/updates have been successful else we rollback.

However, I am being advised by my senior dev that this will significantly impact performance, even with a few hundred concurrent users, and that the risk of a corrupt insert/update (i.e. where only some of the tables have been updated successfully) is minimal; And that for web apps, transaction protection is not general practice unless they are financial transactions.

The tech stack we are using is Ruby on Rails, MYSQL, running on Heroku.

Comment: It really depends on the applications. Sometimes you can order your inserts so that there's no problem if someone queries before they're all done. But in other cases you can get erroneous results from queries that use inconsistent data betweenthe tables.

Comment: I don't think we can give a general answer to a question like this, you and your organization have to decide whether the tradeoff is appropriate.

Comment: However, I can tell you that my company has been using MyISAM for most of its data for years, with few problems due to lack of transactions. But we've been transitioning to InnoDB, and using transactions in recent applications that insert into lots of related tables.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a general way to approach your question: What will cost more money to your business?

Will it be some corrupted data? (As other says if you work in a critical field it may be the case)

Or will it be performance issue for your average user?